# How to prevent Delphi modifying its DPR (project source) unexpectedly

Tags: delphi, project

To maintain its project, Delphi sometimes adds or removes stuff from the DPR file (project source). I quite like to format my stuff in the DPR as if it is an ordinary unit, for example to group together the 'used' frame references and project source files. I make copies of it and can go back when this happens but every so often, I'll notice that the DPR has had all its source file references smashed into a single block.

Anyone else suffer from this? Is there any way of preventing this from happening (other than a read-only file).
Thanks

Comment: I find it really annoying when it decides to update all the paths from relative to absolute in D2007

Comment: Revision control is the solution.

Comment: @David: More a workaround than a solution.

Comment: @Toto Since Brian is manually making copies of this file, I'd say using some revision control would solve a lot, but your point is valid!

Comment: @David: Right. I was referring to the original problem.

Comment: @David - doesn't sound like a solution or a workaround: if the IDE adds references to dpr and you overwrite from sourceControl you'll likely to nuke important stuff and screw up your project. The project manager is designed to give you an organized view of what's in the dpr. I often edit the 'program' section of the dpr, but not the uses block.

Comment: @Mikey Who said anything about nuking. The code in the .dpr file, even the uses clause is very important and needs to be controlled by the developer and not the IDE. Revision control allows the developer to be in control and accept IDE changes that the developer agrees with, and reject the ones that do harm.

Comment: @David - "The code in the .dpr file, even the uses clause is very important..." - granted. But doesn't the developer also control what the IDE does with the DPR? Assumption is a developer knows what they're doing - if they control it through srcCntrl, they need also to understand the IDE - IDE doesn't do stuff 'just because'. And project options and the project manager give you control. BTW, I'm not 'faint of heart' - I have no problem messing around with  the internals - but my experience with big projects/lots of scattered units(shouldn't have projects like that, but...):Trust the IDE.

Comment: Brian - LEARN MERCURIAL NOW.  :-) http://www.hginit.com

Comment: @Mikey The IDE regularly breaks my .dpr file. My .dpr file has a conditional in its uses clause. Also some of my .dpr files are non-standard in between the begin and end. So no, the developer is not in control of the IDE.

Comment: I do a lot of 'non standard' stuff in the program section of the dpr, never had any problems with the IDE trashing it - of course I always turn off all auto-generated stuff and code a lot of things by hand could be automated, perhaps in ways the IDE would mess with DPR. As for "My .dpr file has a conditional in its uses clause" - could it be that the IDE is giving you a subtle hint that maybe you should find a better design? LOL...

Comment: @Mikey: No - the IDE is giving a not so subtle hint that the design of its project managing could be better. :-)

Comment: @David: Revision control is the only way I get it back!

Comment: @Mikey The condition include is so that I can switch memory managers for different targets. What's your better design for that?

Comment: @David - I understand - I know that sometimes it comes in handy and it's not uncommon when targeting several platforms - VCL does it too. Perhaps an alternative would be to split the implementation of platform generic code from the units handling the conditional usages and have separate units with uses for different memory managers- etc - not much of a solution, I agree - you'd have to set up some indirection to avoid duplication and end up with lot more code to maintain. You have a solution that works for you, who am I to criticize. Just having some fun mostly-it just doesn't LOOK pretty.

Comment: @Mikey I don't like it much either. I can't find anything better. I have a strong preference for including all files other than VCL in my .dpr file rather than using search paths and that leaves me with my current ugly solution.

Answer (score 9):

What I do for most of my projects is to have these 2 files:

1. MyProgram.dpr
2. MyProgramUnit.pas

`MyProgramUnit` has a public method `Main` that contains all the logic from the .dpr (including any conditional defines)

`MyProgram` just calls `Main`.

**Edit 1:**

You can put uses lists in `MyProgramUnit.pas`, but they don't automatically become part of your project.
That might or might not be an issue, it depends if you like having Delphi finding units in a search path, or add files to your project to make them visible.

What you can do, is to document the uses-lists in `MyProgramUnit.pas` and group them by cause. This is what I normally do in most units anyway, not only in the main unit.

**Edit 2:**

Don't go the `{$I MyIncludeFile.inc}` way.
Delphi - especially the IDE - is bad with include files. Code Completion, etc, fail at irregular places.

I've been heavy on include files in the past; not so any more. I even stopped using them for defines, and moved from `{$IFDEF define} ... {$ENDIF}` towards `{$IF Constant1 >= Constant2} ... {$IFEND}`.

Comment: +1 That's an excellent idea. Can you put all the uses in there too?

Comment: You can use whatever units you want, @David. But using units in MyProgramUnit doesn't make them part of the project, so there's no reason for that unit to use anything it doesn't directly need.

Comment: @Rob So that makes this sort of a half solution.

Comment: What about {$I MyMain.inc} and put the code that must be kept safe from the .dpr in the .inc file? I must admit I'm not a fan of include files, amd I have never tried this, but would the IDE accept this? Who tried this and can tell more about it?

Comment: +1 that's what we do for console projects. Should have a look at it again for client and server projects...

Comment: @Marjan I use it to switch from a console based unit-test app to a UI one and back. And between a Windows Service and a regular process: two different .dpr files sharing the same main unit.

Comment: @Jeroen: I only mentioned it as a possibility for the .dpr file. As I said, I am not a big fan of include files myself, for various reasons. But I think it might perhaps solve the particular problem of the OP. I never tried this, though

Comment: @Rudy: that's what I indeed understood. Even for .dpr, I don't like include files. For instance, a lot of refactorings seem unreliable when using include files. Any case: include or not, the best is to keep as little logic as possible in the .dpr.

Answer (score 7):

The .dpr is a normal Delphi file, alright, but once it is opened in the IDE, it is more or less "owned" by the IDE. There is no way to stop the IDE from adding or removing code from it, when the IDE thinks that is necessary (e.g. when you added a unit, changed some settings, etc.). That can also mean it reformats parts of the code.

If you want "immutable" code, put it in a unit.

Comment: ... Or don't use the IDE at all. Use notepad and the command line compiler.  :-)  I've long since given up and realized that the Delphi IDE owns the .dpr file and anything I write in the Uses clause up there, especially, could get changed.  It's up to me to commit or revert that change (version control). Anybody NOT USING Version Control plus doing off-site backups; well... I pity da fool

Comment: Well, instead of Notepad, I'd probably use a better editor, but it is possible. Real programmers...

Comment: real programmers ... use VIM.

Comment: @Warren - "I pity da fool" +1

Answer (score 1):

I think Rudy's got this one right.

IMO, it's wiser to keep hands off the dpr uses block in the editor - the project manager is designed to do that - by hand you're liable to corrupt your project settings and introduce some hard to track down bugs in large projects. As for formatting, in Delphi XE there is autoformat that will do your whole project and is configurable.

I often edit the 'program' section of the dpr (that also requires some knowledge and caution) but not the uses block.

One additional point: some of what happens in the dpr can be controlled from your project options settings.

HTH

Comment: The IDE is quite dictatorial about its .dpr and .dpk files. <g>

Answer (score 0):

Personally I make a copy of my uses clause in a giant comment at end of my DPR file.
So when Delphi modifies it, I "restore" it from the comment.
Of Course I have to be cautious of maintaining my "uses comment" up to date.

Note :
I'm using external tools that scan the project file so I cannot use the "external unit" approach, although it seems the cleanest solution.