# What to NOT do to prevent Delphi from mangling the uses list and {$*.RES} in a .DPR

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Every couple of weeks, I bump into this: when doing an IDE operation on the uses units in a Delphi project, it mangles the `.dpr` file.

What happens is that it rebuilds the `uses` list, but gets the position wrong.

I'm wondering what usage pattern to avoid so I won't get into this error again.

I've had this error occur in many Delphi versions. I know it exists in at least Delphi XE2 (it happened there again today), XE, 2007, 2006 and 7.

The mangled fragment usually is structured like this:

```
ususes
  Forms,
  ..
  LastUnitInUses in 'LastUnitInUses.pas';

R *.RES}
```

and should be corrected by removing one `us`, and adding a `{$`:

```
uses
  Forms,
  ..
  LastUnitInUses in 'LastUnitInUses.pas';

{R *.RES}
```

Example file that went wrong:

```
program SysUtilsFormatTests;
{

  Delphi DUnit Test Project
  -------------------------
  This project contains the DUnit test framework and the GUI/Console test runners.
  Add "CONSOLE_TESTRUNNER" to the conditional defines entry in the project options
  to use the console test runner.  Otherwise the GUI test runner will be used by
  default.

}

{$IFDEF CONSOLE_TESTRUNNER}
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF}

ususes
  Forms,
  TestFramework,
  GUITestRunner,
  TextTestRunner,
  SysUtilsFormatUnit in 'SysUtilsFormatUnit.pas';

R *.RES}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  if IsConsole then
    with TextTestRunner.RunRegisteredTests do
      Free
  else
    GUITestRunner.RunRegisteredTests;
end.
```

Example of corrected `.dpr` file:

```
program SysUtilsFormatTests;
{

  Delphi DUnit Test Project
  -------------------------
  This project contains the DUnit test framework and the GUI/Console test runners.
  Add "CONSOLE_TESTRUNNER" to the conditional defines entry in the project options
  to use the console test runner.  Otherwise the GUI test runner will be used by
  default.

}

{$IFDEF CONSOLE_TESTRUNNER}
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF}

uses
  Forms,
  TestFramework,
  GUITestRunner,
  TextTestRunner,
  SysUtilsFormatUnit in 'SysUtilsFormatUnit.pas';

{$R *.RES}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  if IsConsole then
    with TextTestRunner.RunRegisteredTests do
      Free
  else
    GUITestRunner.RunRegisteredTests;
end.
```

Comment: I've had similar problems where Delphi source files contained a mix of Unix-style and Windows-style line endings. Could you check that your `.dpr` only contains Windows-style line endings? An easy way to make sure is to open the file in Notepad (Windows's own version): it only recognises Windows-style line endings, so if it looks different there from how it looks in Delphi, there you go.

Comment: Also, don't have the dpr open in the __active__ source editor tab. You can have it open on another tab, but if it is open in the active tab, I have seen similar problems.

Comment: That's a good one. I'm not sure it was open in the active tab or not.

Comment: I just checked the history tab of my project, and none of the .DPR revisions had "wrong" line endings (all had all their lines end as CRLF)

Comment: Just to be sure: it actually sets `ususes` on line 17? Looks like the `{$` that gets eaten ends up here... Have you tried with `{$IFDEF}{$APPTYPE}{$ENDIF}` on a single line?

Comment: I don't think it matters whether or not the .dpr file is displayed in the IDE

Comment: I often receive this too when creating a new Test Project and then add a new unit to that project... without touching any .dpr file or otherwise... naturally, it doesn't occur _every_ time

Comment: The problem exists also in Delphi XE6

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that I know that works is for you to let the IDE manage the .dpr file.

- Don't add comments.
- Don't use conditionals like $IFDEF.
- Don't modify the code in the .dpr file.

if you do any of these things, expect the IDE to bite back.

Personally I do all of these and fight back at commit time. I use my VCS to defend against bogus IDE changes. It's not ideal, but it's the best option.

Comment: This is while managing the uses list from within the IDE (i.e. add unit, rename unit, etc) and without any $IFDEF in the .DPR, as I'm well aware that the IDE owns the .DPR: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6767221/29290

Comment: I do the same as David: manual reconciliation using VCS on each .DPR change. And there is more pitfalls when editing .DPR manualy e.g. like this [http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=82631](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=82631)

Comment: The file you posted contravenes all three of the items on my list. Not all such mods cause the IDE grief, but you just can't tell what it will do.

Comment: I know: it is the default DUnitTestProjectTemplate.dpr from DUnit shipping with Delphi XE2. I probably should have written "no additional IFDEFs or comments".

Comment: I do a lot of weird stuff in my DPR. As a result, every time I open my project I have to manually open my main form and a datamodule so I don't lose references to them from other forms. I'll try the approach of using a different unit for this.

Comment: @Leonardo If you have to open a referred form/datamodule to get its reference, try check form's/module's name in curly brackets in uses clause in .DPR file. It seems to me that IDE has simplified mechanism and finds reference in cached modules and if they are not there, it scans names defined as comments in uses clause.